# how to find a file in remote directory which contains 10000s of files and folders

Tags: python

I have used this below code. But As it contains a lots of files and folders its taking lots of time.

```
 for localDirname, localDirnames, localFilenames in os.walk('.'):
        for localFilename in localFilenames:
            if  fullFileName == localFilename :
                 print "File found"
```

Comment: There's quite a lot to be googled on `os.walk` being slow. Perhaps you can try [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir). Other people have used `listdir` recursively, or (if you're on *nix), you can try using using`find` through `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not needing to recursively walk a remote directory `os.listdir` could provide a faster option.

```
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if fullFileName in f:
        print "File found"
```

Comment: It should run recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can `try` with `open` or `os.stat`. You can also keep a list of folders where it can be for trying each.

Also, it will always be quicker to use @Evert's idea.